Display output from Vertex AI Agent builder
I've used Agent Builder to create a conversational agent and have integrated with Slack. The agent works perfectly in my Slack channel but does not display the final output or recommendation.
What step am I missing?
I have tried

manually adding the generated output in the examples I have created but to no avail.
written an explicit instruction to display the output
reinstalled the app several times in the Slack workspace after the above changes

